# How can I send an ssh command to the background in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following line in a script:

```
output=$(sudo ssh root@172.20.209.11 "/etc/config/users/pzsr7z/scripts-modified/scripts/wizard/enroller 10.193.22.236 22 WDCCRNMTS001 WDCCR-1-COMPT-R102 8")
```

How can I send that to the background so that the script can continue on with the rest of its lines while this line is processing the background?

I tried putting an & at the end of the line but I ended up getting some odd behavior (keystrokes were not being processed properly)

Comment: Do you still intend the capture to complete? You can't capture a background process's output into a variable.

Comment: ...also, generally speaking, using `sudo` to invoke `ssh` is something of a smell -- unless you need to escalate privileges to read a private key (which even then is best done with a non-root account), that typically indicates Doing It Wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yep, I am trying trying to capture the output of the command so that I can verify that the remote ssh command completed correctly. Would there be a way to do that? Also the sudo command is being used to access an SSH key. Multiple people would be using this command, so I felt that having the key located under the root user's directory would be the easiest way to allow the users access to it.

Comment: The thing about using root is that you're giving folks permissions to much, much more than just this one key. I'd suggest putting the users who need access to the command in a UNIX group (hereafter calling it `keygroup`), and setting the key to be owned by `root:keygroup` with permissions `750`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I unfortunately cannot do that easily. This would be running on an opengear appliance, and in order to run the commands properly (the enroller script for example) the users need to use the sudo command or be logged in as root

Comment: ...btw, I've amended my answer to show how you really ought to be looking at exit status rather than output to determine success if at all possible. (If your remote command doesn't reflect success or lack thereof in its exit status, that's best considered a bug and fixed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok great, the remote command does return an exit status, so this should work perfectly

Comment: To be clear -- I'm not suggesting that you make `enroller` work without root on the remote system, but that you use a UNIX group to provide access-control to the key (that provides remote root) on the *local* system.

Comment: BTW, the `$(<filename)` syntax in my answer is a bashism -- that is, it's only guaranteed to work if your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`; since this question was tagged bash, I presume that's a safe assumption.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy going to see if I can do that. I'm not sure if anything is managing the groups on this system (there is a web gui that allows you to add users to the system) so I'll approach that with caution

Comment: Another approach is to have a `keyuser` account, and have folks `sudo -u keyuser ssh [...]`; it's not an ideal practice, but better than sharing out root. (Ideally, the sudoers entry for `keyuser` would only allow a very specific set of SSH commands, and its config would turn off the `PermitLocalCommand` ssh setting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect stdin from /dev/null, and stdout and stderr to file:

```
cmd="/etc/config/users/pzsr7z/scripts-modified/scripts/wizard/enroller 10.193.22.236 22 WDCCRNMTS001 WDCCR-1-COMPT-R102 8"
ssh root@172.20.209.11 "$cmd" </dev/null >enroller.log 2>&1 & ssh_pid=$!
```

...then, later, you can wait for it to complete and read the file:

```
if wait "$ssh_pid"; then
  echo "Remote command exited with a successful exit status" >&2
else
  echo "Remote command exited with a failed exit status" >&2
fi
output=$(<enroller.log)
```